# Shows vs. suggests: Is there a substantive difference?

Tags: writing

Research is sometimes described as “showing” or “suggesting” a result.

Is there any substantive or objective difference between the two descriptions?

One example is here, in this answer it is said economic research “shows”, which seems intuitively less appropriate to me, but maybe that’s not true:
https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/600/38455

Comment: It might vary between disciplines.  In mathematics, "shows" means the same as "proves"; "A shows that B" would be a claim that A is conclusive proof that B is true.  "A suggests that B" would only say that this is evidence pointing toward B being more likely to be true.

Comment: This can be answered definitively by consulting an English language dictionary. Of which there are many online. The Oxford English dictionary gives "Demonstrate or prove." as the third meaning when combined with an object. On the other hand the 2nd meaning of "suggests" is "Cause one to think that (something) exists or is the case". In other words they differ in the degree of certainty they indicate.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant the question is not what the general dictionary definition is.  Rather, what meaning is implied in the context of referring to research results.

Comment: Research published in English is still in English. I think you'll find that any usage peculiar to research will still be documented in a good dictionary, albeit not as the first entry.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant your comments are helpful.  It helps point out that one possible answer is, the terms have no different implication or connotation from anything else.  They could just be words, look them up, or they could have certain implications when they relate to describing a research result.

Comment: Perhaps what's confusing is that research is an ongoing process and often simply wrong. Researchers may in good faith,*think* they have "shown" something (in the sense of proving or demonstrating as fact), but they have errors in their reasoning or experiments. For example, in the early part of the 20th century it had been definitively "shown" that beta decay had a complex discrete spectra. It turned out that the experiments were flawed, so by the middle of the century physicists had definitively "shown" that, beta decay spectra were continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what my take on these two words.

"Shows" refers to "It is true" i.e. the conclusion follows from the evidence with probability of 1. For example, the results obtained in this study 'shows' whenever x is increased, y is decreased by 2.78. Therefore, we conclude that...

"Suggests" refers to "It is highly likely to be true" i.e. the conclusion is not certain to be followed from the evidence. For example, our study suggests an increase in parameter x results in y decreasing by 2.78. Since the present study is constrained in the domain of the parameters x and y, it could be concluded that ...

Comment: helpful perspective. i’ve marked it as the accepted answer.  i’ve tried at the same time simplify the question for broadest application.  if you find the question useful, please consider upvoting.  thank you for the answer.